# Como limpar ou resetar formulario com Angular2

Tags: angular

Como posso limpar os campos de um formulario com Angular2? Preciso dar um reset no formulario

Estou usando a versão final do angular 2 no meu projeto

Answer (score 1):

Os campos de seu formulário está vinculados a um modelo, certo?

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="cadastro.nome" name="cadastro-nome />
```

Coloque uma chamada para um método:

```
<button (click)="resetForm">Redefinir</button>
```

E no código do método, redefina o seu modelo:

```
resetForm(){

    this.formulario = {
          nome:' '
    }

}
```

Se a estrutura do seu formulário estiver em uma classe, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
resetForm(){

  this.formulario = new Formulario();

}
```

Comment: Valeu!! Resolveu da segunda forma, na estrutura de classe